# Prolog pathfinding stuck in a loop after found the answer

Tags: prolog

I have my code to find all the possible solutions in a given grid from point A to B, My problem is after finding all the solutions, it will start to trace back and forth forever. I guess it's legal because all the conditions are met. However, I have trouble giving out a condition that will prevent that. Any help?

```
move([X,Y], e, [X1,Y]) :- X1 is X+1.
move([X,Y], n, [X,Y1]) :- Y1 is Y+1.
move([X,Y], s, [X,Y1]) :- Y1 is Y-1.

safe([Xn,Yn],[Xg,Yg]) :-
  Xg >= Xn,
  Xn > 0,
  Yg >= Yn,
  Yn > 0. %next state must be whit-in grid otherwise false

%% solve([X,Y],[TargetX,TargetY],[Xg,Yg],[FirstMove|OtherMoves])

solve([X,Y],[X,Y],_,[]) :- !.
solve([X,Y],[Xt,Yt],[Xg,Yg],[Fm|Om]) :-
  move([X,Y],Fm,[Xn,Yn]),
  safe([Xn,Yn],[Xg,Yg]),
  solve([Xn,Yn],[Xt,Yt],[Xg,Yg],Om).
```

output:

```
?- solve([1,1],[2,2],[2,2],P).
P = [e, n] ;
P = [n, e] ;
P = [n, s, e, n] ;
P = [n, s, n, e] ;
P = [n, s, n, s, e, n] ;
P = [n, s, n, s, n, e] ;
P = [n, s, n, s, n, s, e, n] ;
P = [n, s, n, s, n, s, n, e] ;
P = [n, s, n, s, n, s, n, s, e|...] ;
P = [n, s, n, s, n, s, n, s, n|...] ;
```

Comment: All you want is to avoid dublicates in P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
solve(A,B,C,D):-
  solve(A,B,C,D,[]).

solve([X,Y],[X,Y],_,[],_) :- !.
solve([X,Y],[Xt,Yt],[Xg,Yg],[Fm|Om],Chars) :-
  move([X,Y],Fm,[Xn,Yn]),
  \+ member(Fm,Chars),
  safe([Xn,Yn],[Xg,Yg]),
  solve([Xn,Yn],[Xt,Yt],[Xg,Yg],Om, [Fm|Chars]).

?- solve([1,1],[2,2],[2,2],P).
P = [e, n] ;
P = [n, e] ;
false.
```

All I did was to introduce another variable `Chars` which holds the visited nodes (?) and every time a move is tried it checks, if this move was already taken by asking if `Fm` is not a member of the list `Chars` (`\+ member(Fm,Chars)`). `Fm` is added to `Chars` in the recursive calls.

Comment: Not really, because if it has a bigger grid, say 5x5, there will be more than 2 same movements then this will fail.

Comment: so what are your criteria where it should fail?

Comment: Thank you, I changed direction n,s, and e to their actual coordinates like move([X,Y], [X,Y], [X,Y1]) :- Y1 is Y-1., 
then I was able to track them in the Char. All worked out!

Comment: ah ok, I did not realize the letters were directions only.